# Concatenation in a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a problem with this selector, I don't know why it isn't working, it's driving me nuts.

I have this:

```
variable = "#2";

$('"'+variable+'"').css("background-color", "red");
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgqYJ.png

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: only `$(var)` should work.

Comment: var variable = "#2"; $(variable).css("background-color", "red");

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `concatenation` in this case. You can use `variable` directly as selector.

```
$(variable).css("background-color", "red");
```

1. Use the variable as it is in the `jQuery` as `selector`
2. Change the name of the variable to something else as `javascript` has it as reserved keyword.